# Replicate a code to obtain m different output

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, replication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KLCl.png)

The DataV present two data V1 and V2 I obtained from a bivariate log-normal distribution.

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(21)
X<-mvrnorm(n = 40, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 2, 2, 5), ncol = 2))
Y<-exp(X)
DataV <-as.data.frame(Y)
```

I then produced a 95% confidence interval for the correlation test based on Fisher’s z-transform. To obtain this interval I used `with(DataV, cor.test(V1,V2)$conf.int)`.

My aim is to replicate the code so that I will have m different confidence intervals.

I tried to use 'rep', 'replicate', and even 'list' (as you see in that example), but it actually replicate the same CI instead of different ones.

```
listA = list() # Make an empty list to save output in
for (i in 1:3) { # Indicate number of iterations with "i"
    listA[[i]] = with (DataY, cor.test(V1,V2)$conf.int) # Save output in list for each iteration
}
listA
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make a function out of the operation you want to replicate:

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(0815)
fun_rep <- function(){
  X<-mvrnorm(n = 40, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 2, 2, 5), ncol = 2))
  Y<-exp(X)
  DataY <-as.data.frame(Y)
  with (DataY, cor.test(V1,V2)$conf.int)
}

replicate(10, fun_rep())
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]     [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
# [1,] 0.3286053 0.6030402 0.2133789 0.8569425 0.5625251 0.471498 0.3792115 0.7632626 0.5622085 0.4234303
# [2,] 0.7555212 0.8722339 0.6968450 0.9584212 0.8567383 0.819872 0.7792942 0.9286401 0.8566151 0.7991648
```

Each column represents a new iteration, and the rows are the output confidence interval bounds. For m CIs, replace 10 by m. Does this help?